# PLSQL Array of Record to out parameter

Tags: plsql

I have a scenario where I need to return the following to frontend UI from PL/SQL procedure. Can you please help me with the logic and code.

The following query returns 2 column values, which I require to pass as 1 out parameter to the calling UI procedure:

```
 SELECT emp.EMP_NAME, 
        dep.DEPT_NAME
  FROM  employee emp, 
        department dept
  WHERE dept.DEPT_NO in emp.DEPT_NO
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you tried to concat values and then parse it on the UI side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use department name as argument to provide the employees name associated with that department, you can use it with the function.

```
create or replace function get_employees1(dep varchar2) return id_tab1 is

    l_emp_list id_tab1; ---id_tab1 is a table of varchar2(CREATE OR REPLACE type id_tab1 as table of varchar2(10);)
    str varchar2(300);

begin

    str := 'select e.last_name from employees e join departments d on 
           e.department_id=d.department_id 
           where d.department_name= :dep';

    execute immediate str bulk collect into l_emp_list using dep; 

    return l_emp_list;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for astute help. Made a slight customisation to suit for my purpose.